# Add an interval day to a date from postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date

I would like to add a day to a date from postgreSQL, so i tried this one :

```
SELECT * FROM t_ask a 
WHERE ask_datesend is null 
AND a.ask_date_reception >= ('2019-06-12' + INTERVAL '1 day');
```

But it doesn't work.

But if i try that i have an answer :

```
SELECT * FROM t_ask a 
WHERE ask_datesend is null 
AND a.ask_date_reception >= '2019-06-12'
```

Little precision in a.ask_date_reception the date is like

> "2019-06-12 15:28:01.982"

Answer (score 0):

Try an explicit conversion:

```
a.ask_date_reception >= ('2019-06-12'::date + INTERVAL '1 day');
```

Or use `timestamp` or `timestamp with time zone` instead of `date`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! In which case i have to put "::", is it just to precise the type?

Comment: @LikerGotham . . . That is Postgres shorthand for a type conversion.